# MongoDB. Compare two collections field by field. Script is crashing on nested array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to compare two collection with lot of nested objects and arrays. Here is a structure of a document
[image: structure of a single document]

Here is my code

```
function iterate_array (my_array, path, cur_id) {
    for(item in my_array) {
            if (item == "cloudTimestamp") {
                    continue;
            } else if (typeof my_array[item] == "object") {
                    var x = path.slice();
                    x.push(item);
                    iterate_array(my_array[item], x, cur_id);
            } else if (typeof my_array[item] == "function") {
                    continue;
            } else {
                    other_val = otherdb.product.findOne({"_id" : cur_id});
                    if (path == '') {
                            if (my_array[item] == other_val[item]) {
                                    print("field matched");
                            } else {
                                    print("field NOT matched");
                            }
                    } else {
                            var string_path = JSON.stringify(path).replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9,]/g, '').replace(/,/g, '.');
                            if (my_array[item] == other_val[string_path][item]) {
                                    print("field matched");
                            } else {
                                    print("field NOT matched");
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
}

var db = db.getSiblingDB('smcdb_bos_new');
var otherdb = db.getSiblingDB('smcdb_boa_new');
var cursor = db.product.find();
cursor.forEach( function (mydoc) {
    iterate_array(mydoc, [], mydoc['_id']);
});
```

Script works until it reaches XrefHistory.values array. Then it crashes with the following error:

```
2016-01-19T07:15:38.566-0500 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at compare.js:22
```

Comment: perhaps you are missing array index, e.g. XrefHistory.0.myfieldName, where 0 is the array index?

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in your code:

```
var string_path = JSON.stringify(path).replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9,]/g, '').replace(/,/g, '.');
if (my_array[item] == other_val[string_path][item]){
...
} else
{
}
```

you are trying to access data with `string_path` from `other_val`, which is not going to work. what you are trying to do is `other_val['a.b.c']`, which should actually be something like `other_val['a']['b']['c']` or `other_val.a.b.c.`. So the key is not found, thus reading 0 from undefined.